# Building single page application using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express

Without any framework for front end, now I'm facing issue with navigation. I have a sidebar that when clicked will call my template, loaded and rendered properly.

I merely do `res.render('index',{layout:false})` in my server side. I tried pjax, it worked too. I have one biggest issue.

for example everything worked at `localhost:1000/lists`, suddenly user click refresh, I can't see the layout because that view excluded the layout.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this, but when you navigate, you change the layout, but then when you refresh the page, the layout resets?

Comment: I think that you're not using routes, you navigate but the url stays untouched, when the user hits refresh, the browser reloads the current url. I think from what I understand

Comment: You should also manage browser history stack as far as I think

Comment: @ItsGreg when I'm on localhost:1000 I use the layout template, and I load it for example item.handlebars which doesn't include the layout. the url now became localhost:1000/item. But when the user click refresh, it hit res.render('item'), and the layout is gone, everything break.

Comment: @mjoia, I was using normal http request routing, everything work fine. Now I want to ajax call every endpoint or res.render to achieve better UX.

Comment: You can't use virtual directories in url on client side if routing at server isn't set up to point to entry point of client side app and client side routing then populates needed resources. Post routing code and proper description of the problem

Comment: @charlietfl take a look on this http://pjax.herokuapp.com. My problem is the user's reload will hit the endpoint of my templates which excluded from its layout.